# Using native methods in a JavascriptObject class 

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

I'm currently trying out my first gwt app with gwt-map library. 
I'm having problem accessing getLatitude() and other similar methods on ClientLocation class. I'm new to gwt and needless to say JavaScriptObject

[update]
I realized that I have to include

```
private native ClientLocation getUser() /*-{

  return $wnd.jsonData[0]; 
}-*/;
```

to access the methods. However, I'm prompted with the following error

> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException:
>   (TypeError): Cannot read property '0'
>   of undefined  stack: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property '0' of undefined

after executing

```
ClientLocation user = getUser();
```

How should I create an instance for ClientLocation ? 
Any help or ideas will be much appreciated...

gwt-map Library:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted

API for ClientLocation:
http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.1/com/google/gwt/ajaxloader/client/ClientLocation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out..

```
ClientLocation user = AjaxLoader.getClientLocation();
```

Hope this will help other first timers with gwt and gwt-map

Answer (score 1):

That `TypeError` you're seeing is JavaScript's equivalent to a `NullPointerException`.  It's likely that the `jsonData` property is not defined on the host window.  You can verify this by using the Chrome developer tools console or FireBug's console to evaluate `window.jsonData` to ensure that it is defined.